# Python one line if statement with two actions

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I am trying to find a way to get two actions done in one line if statement, I can find a lot of answers to perform a single action in if statement one-liner but not for this. Is it even possible? I tried something like this but failed with ValueError - too many values to unpack (expected 2). Thanks.

```
g, er = "id", "err" if no_of_errs <= 1 else "ppd", "ers"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python is looking at your code like this:

```
 g, er = ( "id" )  ,  ( "err" if no_of_errs <= 1 else "ppd" )   , ( "ers" )
```

3 things to unpack, only 2 to pack it into.

The reason behind the error is *operator priority*, you can either read lots of  lenghty text [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html)  or google it and find a table like [here](http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~valerie/courses/fall10/155/resources/op_precedence.html).

---

Fix it by makeing the tuples explicit with parenthesis:

```
no_of_errs = 0
g, er = ("id", "err") if no_of_errs <= 1 else ("ppd", "ers")
print(g,er)

no_of_errs = 10
g, er = ("id", "err") if no_of_errs <= 1 else ("ppd", "ers")
print(g,er)
```

Output:

```
id err
ppd ers
```

With explicit tuples, no more operator confusion and it works.

---

Keywords for google: `operator` `priority` `precedence` or smth alike

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation, appreciate it @Patrick Artner